# What is the correct way to manage module dependencies when using Prism?

Tags: visual-studio, prism, project-management, dependency-management

I'm experimenting with Prism, and I've run into a number of inconveniences caused by the fact that the Shell project does not directly reference the Module projects. The primary inconvenience is that the modules output assembly and it's dependencies are not copied to the shell projects output folder after compilation. I've been successful in using xcopy as a post-build event to copy the target assembly to the projects output folder (which is not particularly nice, but seems to work), but not the dependencies.

Is there a standard way to solve this, or is it mostly ad-hoc solutions? Having to set a post-build event for every configuration in every module seems excessive, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution for this. You can set up project dependencies in Visual Studio without creating cross-references in the assemblies.

Open the solution properties and go to the **Project Dependencies** page. Here, select in the combo box **Projects** your main EXE that contains your shell. Alternatively, right click your main project in the Solution Explorer and select **Project Dependencies...** there:

[image]

In the **Depends on** listbox, check mark all your module projects that need to be compiled / copied in the output directory.

You can configure further dependencies for all your projects in the solution (e.g. if you have indirect dependencies between modules).

On changing any project that has dependencies, all dependent project will be rebuilt by Visual Studio and processed according the build configuration (e.g. copied to the output directory).

Comment: Thank you. I knew this couldn't be as complicated as google made it out to be.